# U+2069 error when adding image in TeXShop

Tags: graphics, floats, errors, unicode

I am trying to add an image into the document on TeXShop but keep seeing this error:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character (U+2069) (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.

l.9 ...udegraphics{12g}
```

I saw an answer on another thread saying I should retype that line with ASCII but I don't know or understand how to do that.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {/Desktop⁩/Plots/} }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{12g}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to fix the issue? Any thought would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You have an invisible extra character after `Desktop` in `\graphicspath{ {/Desktop⁩/Plots/} }`. You can check this with [this tool](https://pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover/).

Comment: Do you really mean `/Desktop` which starts at the root of you hard drive?

Comment: "retype with ascii" means "use your keyboard, do not copy and paste".  Copy/paste tends to bring along strange extra characters that marmot mentioned.

Comment: @Alan Munn Thank you very much and also others users.